# Display m2m field defined via 'through' in admin

Tags: django, admin, models, m2m

I have the following model classes:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField('category', max_length=200, blank=False)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=200, blank=False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False, through='Book_Category')

class Book_Category(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

When adding a new book object in admin interface I would like to also add a new category, and book_category relationship.

If I include **categories** in BookAdmin as

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['categories', ]}), ...
```

I get `can't include the ManyToManyField field 'categories' because 'categories' manually specifies a 'through' model` error.

Is there any way to achieve required functionality?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
class CategoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book_Category
    extra = 3 # choose any number

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CategoryInline,)

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)