# How to insert data form in manytomany through a model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

I'm implementing a simple platform sales, one section of this platform references to insert the many orders that are set up, this orders (`Pedido`) are related to an order_detail (`Detalle_Pedido`) and this to product (`Producto`) like this:

```
    class Pedido(models.Model):
        referencia = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente,related_name="cliente")
        fecha_pedido = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        fecha_entrega = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        agencia_envio = models.ForeignKey(Envio, related_name="entrega",blank=True,null=True)
        producto = models.ManyToManyField(Producto, through='Detalle_Pedido')

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.referencia

        class Meta:
            ordering = ["referencia","fecha_pedido"]



    class Detalle_Pedido(models.Model):
        pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, related_name="pedido")
        producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, related_name="producto")
        unidad_precio = models.FloatField()
        cantidad = models.IntegerField()
        descuento = models.FloatField(blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.producto

        class Meta:
            ordering = ["producto"]



     class Producto(models.Model):
        referencia = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        cantidad = models.IntegerField()
        precio_unidad = models.FloatField(blank=True)
        cantidad_en_pedido = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
        descatalogado = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
        proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,related_name="proveedor",blank=True,null=True)
        categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria,related_name="categoria",blank=True,null=True)
        imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to="/media/productos", blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.nombre

        class Meta:
            ordering = ["nombre","cantidad","precio_unidad","cantidad_en_pedido","descatalogado"]
```

Every time an order in `Pedido` is created, through `Detalle_Pedido` I have to relate each order detail with the new created order and when create each order detail relate with a `Producto` so user can set the product and quantity for the order detail, I'm using a `CreateView`, I know this could be do with `formsets` but I see examples and I'm not clarify with the fact of use with `ManyToManyFields` through a model, in this case, `Detalle_Pedido`

**Edit:**

I'm clarify some issues for make more understanding, first of all `Detalle_Pedido`, yes, is an item part of an order that's why I define a foreign key targeting to `Pedido`(an order), an order has many items, `Detalle_Pedido`(order detail) has another foreign key targeting to `Producto`(product) for retrieve the product details, from `Pedido`I did a `ManyToManyField` to `Producto` because one order have some products and for that, i set the clause `through`saying that I want to store some data related to the order and product, that's the order detail (`Detalle_Pedido`), I don't know if that's the more "legit" way to do that but is a little approach for what I'm trying to do, I'm relative new in Django so I miss many things, any advice or tip would be more appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you would have a m2m relationship there in the first place. As far as I can see the Detalle_Pedido is an item part of an Pedido. It does not make sense to have a single item on an order to be referenced to several orders. Are you sure you don't want to have a one-to-many relationship here? And could you edit your question to include a more succinct and specific question?

Comment: Have a look at a question I asked a few days ago, I think this applies to what you're doing as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17515439/1254292

Comment: Check out this one as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832767/display-m2m-field-defined-via-through-in-admin

Comment: I've edited with some explanations.

Comment: For more understanding, you can see the example for Northwind Database, the related tables for order, order_detail and product looks like the same http://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/

Comment: Finally you answer works fine to me, thanks :)